# Membership provider and MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I have a database that has been in place for a few years. One of our web apps uses Membership Provider and the tables in the database that were created when it was setup. This older app uses MVC 4.0.

I have a new web app that I am creating that needs to use the same database. When I created the project, it used MVC 5.

The new app does not need to use the same logins as the older application but it does need to use the same database for other data in it.

This is where my problem lies. Should/could I use Membership Provider since that is what my users are already using on the other application on the same database this app will be connecting to? Or should I be using Asp.net identity? Can I mix them between applications like that? Should I downgrade my app to use the same MVC version as my older app?

I'm kind of lost as to what path I should take at this point. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your title says MVC6, but in your question you only talk about MVC5. As far as I'm aware, ASP.NET Membership is completely incompatible with ASP.NET Core (MVC6, although it's no longer called that). However, you *can* utilize Membership with MVC5. Regardless, ASP.NET Identity is the way forward, so any new application should use that, and updating older apps to move to Identity should, at the very least, be in your pipleline.

Comment: I fixed the typo. What is MVC6 called now?

Comment: It's just ASP.NET Core. MVC and Web Api are no longer separate frameworks and Web Forms is gone so it's just one thing now: ASP.NET Core.